# Include SVN tag in Javadoc - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to include the SVN $Id$ tag to my Javadoc description. My javadoc above each class should be the following:

```
/**
 * Simple Description.
 *
 * @author theexiile1305, mymail@mail.com
 * @version $Id: MyClass.java, $LastChangedRevision$, $LastChangedDate$, mifuchs $
 */
```

I have tried the following steps:

- I added in the SVN-Properties window in eclipse the following entry

  - name: `svn:keywords`
  - value `svn:keywords=Id`
- After that, I committed the File and nothing happens. This means the javadoc comment above the class is still the same.

Why does this still not work?

Comment: Outside your IDE, have a look at the commited file as a regular text file to see if anything is different.

Comment: There isn't anything different like the IDE. Same Problem

Comment: The value of property svn:keywords should be Id (and not svn:keywords=Id). And the line in comment of your code shoud be @version $Id$, the $id$ being automatically expanded by SVN. Also perform a svn update.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! ;-)

Comment: OK. I've added an answer. Please accept it by clicking on "Accept" if it suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that it works, you have to do the following:

1. The value of SVN property `svn:keywords` should be `Id` instead of `svn:keywords=Id` as you've written in your post.
2. The line in comment of your code shoud be `@version $Id$`, the `$id$` being automatically expanded by SVN.
3. Commit this, then perform a `svn update`

And it should work like a charm !